# How to Test That a static Constant Value Is Passed Into MailService sendMail closure WIthout Requiring a class Prefix on the Constant?

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

My grails Unit Test mocks out the MailService using an Expando and redefining the sendMail method. The original code uses a static constant called EMAIL_SUBJECT without a prefix. However, when I run the test and remove from **Something.EMAIL_SUBJECT** the "Something." it fails the assertion saying that mockMailService.subject was passed a **null** How can I improve the test so the "Something." is not needed on EMAIL_SUBJECT?

Snippet of Test Code:

```
def createMockMailService() {

    def mockMailService = new Expando()

    mockMailService.sendMail = { callable ->

        callable.delegate = mockMailService
        callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        callable.call()
    }

    mockMailService.subject = { header -> }

    mockMailService
}

void testThis() {
    def mockMailService = createMockMailService()

    mockMailService.subject = { assert it == "value of constant"  }

    Something something = new Something()
    something.mailService = mockMailService

    something.doSomethingThatCallsMailService()
}
```

Code Under Test:

```
class Something {

    static def EMAIL_SUBJECT = "value of constant"

    def mailService = new SomeMailThing()

    def doSomethingThatCallsMailService() {
            mailService.sendMail {
            subject Something.EMAIL_SUBJECT // Remove Something prefix
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour is strange on the first glance only. Root cause is the `DELEGATE_FIRST` resolution strategy combined with delegate being an Expando instance in this case. `DELEGATE_FIRST` looks for the `EMAIL_SUBJECT` property in the delegate first, which is `mockMailService`, which is an Expando. Expando doesn't throw `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` on missing properties, instead it returns null. Thus the property is found on the delegate and not evaluated on the owner (which would be the `Something` you want the property from).

You could change the resolution strategy to `OWNER_FIRST`. If you want to stick with `DELEGATE_FIRST` because the original `mailService` calls the `sendMail` closure parameter with this strategy, you can't use Expando for your mocked mail service. Instead you could use an ordinary object and do the metaprogramming on the metaClass.

It would look something like this:

```
def createMockMailService() {
   def mockMailService = new Object()
   mockMailService.metaClass.sendMail = { callable ->
      callable.delegate = mockMailService
      callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
      callable.call()
   }
   mockMailService.metaClass.subject = { header -> }
   mockMailService
}
```

Comment: Nice job explaining why the property was being "found" on the Expando object (null). Using an ordinary object and doing the metaprogramming on the metaClass is a wonderful idea! It works too! Thanks!